# Automator actions for adding spotlight comments to a batch from excel/text document?

Tags: metadata

I want to take data directly from a table in a pdf or excel spreadsheet, and add it, several files at a time, to the spotlight comment fields for a list of files. Is there a way to do this?

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I believe it's not possible in the graphical Automator, because it doesn't have commands needed to parse CSV files. Except by embedding a script to handle the text parsing with "Run shell script".

Also, you can use AppleScript, which can be added as Folder actions (Right click a folder -> Folder Actions Setup...). There's already a script for adding spotlight comments to image files in a folder, it could be customizable to do what you need.

Edit:

Not sure what kind of formats you have the data in, but I made a Folder Action script that works with simple comma-delimited text files (or CSV files), which is something that you should get out of many spreadsheet programs: http://ge.tt/38P9NHV/v/0?c , see if it's any help.

Comment: thanks for putting this together IH!  I just used it on a project I'm working on and it executed perfectly.  Question, is there a way to do this procedure without copying all the files?

Answer (score 0):

Sound Miner Pro v.4 can do this for sound files. Unfortunately, it's $400

Comment: Actually, @Kai V4 is $600, V4Pro is $900. http://store.soundminer.com/macintosh-products.html